# Remove Object on Transition Complete

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am spawning some rectangles and each rectangle is transitioned to move down the screen. I am trying to remove those rectangle from the memory for which the transactions are complete ( means rectangles which are moved down the screen and are no more visible on screen). But instead the visible (newly spawned) rectangles are removed.

Here is my code

```
--table to hold dynamically created rectangles
local rects={}
--used as index for table
local numRect=0

local function removeRect( obj )
    local rectid = obj.id

    obj:removeSelf( )
    rects[rectid] = nil
end

--function for spawning rectangles
local function spawnRect()
    numRect = numRect + 1
    rects[numRect] = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, 100, 100, 100)
    rects[numRect]:setFillColor( 1,1,1 )
    rects[numRect].id = numRect

    transition.to( rects[numRect], {time = 9000, y = display.contentHeight + 100,
            onComplete = function()
                removeRect(rects[numRect])
            end

    } )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, spawnRect, -1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

The onComplete listener already receives the object that was being transitioned. So, you don't need to pass it.

Just change your transition.to to have onComplete = removeRect, as below:

```
transition.to( rects[numRect], {time = 9000, y = display.contentHeight + 100,
        onComplete = removeRect } )
```